# Gettings 2nd Popup After Closing First

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form which dynamically generates a table of attached (uploaded) files to the form. The last cell of each row is a delete button. That delete button when clicked executes this code:

**Delete Button Clicked**

```
$("td").on("click", ".btn-danger", function(event){

    var rowID = "#"+$(this).attr("rowID");
    var id = $(this).attr("id");

    $("#confirmDelete").animate({top:'15%'}, 1000);
    $("#confirmDelete").removeClass("hidden");

    $("#confirmDelete").on("click", "#deleteFile", function(e){

        var inn = document.thisItem.getInnovator();
        var getInfo =  inn.newItem("CSH_PLI_CommercialPartFiles", "get");
        getInfo.setProperty("related_id", id);
        getInfo = getInfo.apply();
        var relatedID = getInfo.getProperty("id", "");
        var thisRelated = inn.newItem("CSH_PLI_CommercialPartFiles", "delete");
        thisRelated.setID(relatedID);
        thisRelated = inn.applyAML(thisRelated.ToString());
        var thisFile = inn.newItem("File", "delete");
        thisFile.setID(id);
        thisFile.apply();
             $("#confirmDelete").animate({top:'-100%'}, 1000);
        $("#confirmDelete").addClass("hidden");
        $(rowID).hide();
    });

    $("#confirmDelete").on("click", ".btn-default", function (e){
        $("#confirmDelete").animate({top: '-100%'}, 1000);  
    });

});
```

Which in turn brings into focus this bit of HTML, my confirmation window.

**HTML**

```
<div id="confirmDelete">
    <div class="bg-danger">
        <h4>Delete File Confirmation</h4>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p><b>Delete this file? This action cannot be undone</b></p>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="deleteFile">Delete</button>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Now everything works fine enough. Cancel closes the popup. And delete, will actually delete the file from the server and remove it from the table in the form. However, as soon as delete is done, the popup will scroll up and then scroll back down as if it were called again.

I cannot figure out any combination of hides and removes which will actually stop this from happening.

Comment: Try putting different `alert` statements at different breakpoints. Then follow the alerts to see if something is off. Aside: you should cache your jQuery objects such as `$("#confirmDelete")` and `$(this)` instead of always doing lookups.

Comment: @Mikey I have tried the breakpoint and debugger paths. Nothing jumps out.